# How to Save Internet Image with url in SD card (Android Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have error in this code (

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter result)
```

And didn't save image 
i will give you all the code:

MainActivity code:

```
package com.masreta87.backhussian

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.masreta87.backhussian.models.BlogPost
import com.masreta87.backhussian.models.DataSource
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var blogAdapter:BlogRecyclerAdapter
    lateinit var data: List<BlogPost>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        initRecyclerView()
        addDataSet()

    }
    private fun addDataSet(){
        data=DataSource.createDataSet()
        blogAdapter.submitList(data)
    }
    private fun initRecyclerView(){
        recycler_view.apply {
            layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            blogAdapter=BlogRecyclerAdapter()
            adapter=blogAdapter
        }

    }
}
```

and BlogRecyclerAdapter.kt

```
    package com.masreta87.backhussian

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import com.masreta87.backhussian.models.BlogPost
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_blog_list_item.view.*
import java.net.URL
import android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.DownsampleStrategy
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference
import android.widget.Toast
import android.content.Intent
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.net.Uri
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import java.io.IOException


class BlogRecyclerAdapter :RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){
    private  var items:List <BlogPost> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return  BlogViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_blog_list_item,parent,false)

        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when(holder){

            is BlogViewHolder ->{
                holder.bind(items.get(position))
            }
        }
    }
    fun submitList(blogList: List<BlogPost>){
        items = blogList
    }
    class BlogViewHolder constructor(
        itemView:View

    ):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val blogImage:ImageView =itemView.blog_image
        fun bind(blogPost:BlogPost){
            val requestOptions =RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            Glide.with(itemView.context)
                .applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                .load(blogPost.image)
                .into(blogImage)
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                SaveImage(itemView.context,blogPost.image.toString() );
            }

        }

    }


}

private fun SaveImage(context: Context, MyUrl: String) {
    val progress = ProgressDialog(context)

    class SaveThisImage : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
            progress.setTitle("Processing")
            progress.setMessage("Please Wait...")
            progress.setCancelable(false)
            progress.show()
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg arg0: Void): Void? {
            try {

                val sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") val fileName =
                    String.format("%dm.png", System.currentTimeMillis())
                val dir = File(sdCard.absolutePath + "/Image")
                dir.mkdirs()
                val myImageFile = File(dir,fileName) // Create image file
                **var fos:FileOutputStream? = null**
                try {
                    Log.d("ala",myImageFile.toString())
                    **fos = FileOutputStream(myImageFile)**

                    val bitmap = Picasso.get().load(MyUrl).get()
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)

                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE)
                    intent.data = Uri.fromFile(myImageFile)
                    context.sendBroadcast(intent)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } finally {
                    try {
                        fos!!.close()
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }

                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }

            return null
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Void) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            if (progress.isShowing) {
                progress.dismiss()
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    val shareimg = SaveThisImage()
    shareimg.execute()
}
```

And BlogPost.class

```
    package com.masreta87.backhussian.models

data class BlogPost(

                  var image:String

)

{

}
```

AND DataStore.class

```
    package com.masreta87.backhussian.models


class DataSource{

    companion object{

        fun createDataSet(): ArrayList<BlogPost>{
            val list = ArrayList<BlogPost>()
            list.add(
                BlogPost(
                    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/databaseim-56ef5.appspot.com/o/rpic%20(2).jpg?alt=media&token=138c2c3b-33ce-4a96-a7f5-74816af21809"
                )
            )
            list.add(
                BlogPost(
                    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/databaseim-56ef5.appspot.com/o/v1.png?alt=media&token=2e80d218-eb48-4c51-b51a-0fac43f76da7"
                )
            )

            list.add(
                BlogPost(
                    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/databaseim-56ef5.appspot.com/o/v10.jpg?alt=media&token=5e7207eb-1dac-41c0-bb3b-95abf9a54a2e"
                )
            )
            list.add(
                BlogPost(
                    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/databaseim-56ef5.appspot.com/o/v11.jpg?alt=media&token=2ab2b0c4-5ca1-4042-85c5-6d3e58181f45"
                )
            )

            return list
        }
    }
}
```

And Mainifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And layout_blog_list_item.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="610dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/blog_image"
            android:background="@drawable/boder_image"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />






    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

and full error:

> 2020-01-15 21:34:36.509 32083-32083/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.masreta87.backhussian, PID: 32083
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method
>   kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter
>   result
>           at com.masreta87.backhussian.BlogRecyclerAdapterKt$SaveImage$SaveThisImage.onPostExecute(Unknown
>   Source:2)
>           at com.masreta87.backhussian.BlogRecyclerAdapterKt$SaveImage$SaveThisImage.onPostExecute(BlogRecyclerAdapter.kt:86)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

this is full error in app

Comment: Can you post a copy of the stacktrace?

Comment: Since you haven't posted all the stacktrace, I guess you should mark parameter of method doInBackground as nullable.

Comment: i added stacktrace now

Comment: The type returned from `doInBackground` must be same type as parameter in `onPostExecute` method, which in your case are different. Try to change `onPostExecute` parameter to `Void?` and check. Also make sure to change 3rd param type `Void` to `Void?` in AsyncTask class header.

Comment: the error hide , but the image didn't Save in SD card !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the parameter type in

`override fun onPostExecute(result: Void)`

to

`override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?)`.

And as [Akhilesh Kumar mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766686/how-to-save-internet-image-with-url-in-sd-card-android-kotlin/59767623#comment105679382_59766686) you should also change

`class SaveThisImage : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()`

to

`class SaveThisImage : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void?>()`

This is because the `doInBackground` in your code returns a nullable type `Void?`. The return value of `doInBackground` is passed as an argument to `onPostExcecute` but your `onPostExecute` accepts a non null value `Void` instead of a nullable one `Void?`.

As a side-note you should use `Unit` instead of `Void` when in Kotlin

**EDIT**

To make your saved image appear the media database needs to be updated. The media database is updated when you restart your device or after some time passes it will show up in the save location. To update the media database immediately you can use the `MediaScannerConnection` object.

Try passing your saved file to this function after `bitmap.compress` and pass your `myImageFile`

```
/**
 * Updates the Pictures gallery to include the newly created file.
 * @param fileObj: file path to be scanned so that the new file will appear in the gallery
 */
private fun refreshPhoneGallery(fileObj: File)
{

    /* Scan the specified file path so that the new file will appear in gallery */
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
        yourContext,
        arrayOf(fileObj.path),
        null,
        object : MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener
        {
            override fun onScanCompleted(scannedFilePath: String?, p1: Uri?)
            {
                // Do whatever
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: the error hide , but the image didn't Save in SD card

Comment: This can happen because Android needs to re-scan your device to update the media database, you can use the MediaScannerConnection to achieve this. I have updated my answer to include a function you can use.

Comment: the code : fos = FileOutputStream(myImageFile) 
return null here have error

Comment: Can you debug your code to see if `myImageFile` is null?

Comment: no, myImageFile="/Storage/emulated/0/savedImageName/157959992357m.png"

Comment: fos : null , myImageFile : "/Storage/emulated/0/savedImageName/157959992357m.png"

Comment: Its possible you are writing to a location not permitted by your Android version. 

Use the file returned by this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Flashspeed/52cd602e7040a2fa15776bbeacf9ec04). 

Then replace

`val myImageFile = File(dir,fileName)` 

with 

`val myImageFile = createImageFile("Image")`

createImageFile() is the name of the function in the gist

Comment: the myImageFile : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.masreta87.backhussian/files/Pictures/Image/taken_on_Tue-21-Jan-2020-10-20:AM_59c2e60c-878a-48a8-80b8-5fb00a7547f2.jpg
but fos : null